# How to set the settings of scrapy-redis to connect the remote redis-server with password?

Tags: redis, scrapy, remote-access, remote-server

I have tried two solutions:

```
1)`REDIS_HOST = '111.111.111.111'
REDIS_PORT = 12000
REDIS_PASSWORD = 'aaaaaaaa'`
```

but it will raise:

```
    2017-11-23 15:03:13 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yuyanggo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/yuyanggo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 79, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

2)

```
 REDIS_URL = 'redis://:aaaaaaaa@111.111.111.111:12000/0'
```

but I find that the data of redis is saved into localhost,not the remote redis-server.

Comment: To be record,the connect infomation is fictitious.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the following code in your `setting.py` file

```
REDIS_URL = 'redis://:{psw}@{host}:{port}'.format(
    host='xx.xx.xx.xx', # your server ip
    port='xxx', 
    psw='xxxx',
)
```